# How to do a Survey Form to be submitted in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> I want to submit a form in angularjs which are like survey, suppose
>   user will fill the form and submit, I have array of all the questions
>   of form, I want to update all the questions with the respected answers
>   by iterating all the questions from array and update each question
>   individually(why because I only have API to update one question)
>
> This is my form

```
<ng-form name="participateSurveyForm"  novalidate>
        <div class="form_fields_survey_audience" ng-repeat="questionlistitem in surveyquestiondata">        
                 <h3 class="">{{questionlistitem.question}}</h3>
                 <div ng-show="questionlistitem.question_type == 'multiple_choice'">
                    <div class="radio" ng-repeat="optionofanswers in questionlistitem.options">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="optionforanswer" ng-model="surveydataforparticipate.optionforanswer"  ng-value="optionofanswers.option"  required checked>{{optionofanswers.option}}
                            </label>

                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="questionlistitem.question_type == 'open_text'">
                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <textarea class="textAreaMultiligne" name="open_text_field" ng-model="surveydataforparticipate.open_text_field" required  placeholder="Answer Here" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>

                    </div>  
                 </div>
        </div>  <!--End Row-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <button type="submit" ng-click="participateInSurvey(surveydataforparticipate)" class="btn btn-primary">Complete</button>
            </div>
        </div><!--row & Submit Button-->
    </ng-form>      


//Anguar Code

$scope.participateInSurvey = function(surveydataforparticipate){
    angular.foreach(surveydataforparticipate, function(value){

$http.put('/api/survey/question/+value._id, surveydataforparticipate).success(function(data){
 console.log(data);
});
});

}
```

> not getting values from this surveydataforparticipate function. also
>   Is it correct that i have put foreach to submit the data using $http?
>
> Thanks for helping.

Comment: I think you mixed up `optionofanswer` and `optionforanswer`. That's why you are getting `undefined`. Fix that and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in your `controller` where the form should go on `submit`. And, use `ng-submit` to link that function to your form.

```
<ng-form name="participateSurveyForm"  ng-submit="submitForm ()" novalidate>
```

In your controller :

```
$scope.submitForm = function(){
//definition of the function.
//access form data here.
}
```

Comment: Did that but still not getting values of form using $scope, getting undefined.

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve the values? can you show me?